# Is there inconsistency in PostgreSQL syntax of adding constraints to a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

From PostgreSQL document

> To add a constraint, the table constraint syntax is used. For example:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE products ADD CHECK (name <> '');
> ALTER TABLE products ADD CONSTRAINT some_name UNIQUE (product_no);
> ALTER TABLE products ADD FOREIGN KEY (product_group_id) REFERENCES product_groups;
> ```
>
> To add a not-null constraint, which cannot be written as a table
>   constraint, use this syntax:
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE products ALTER COLUMN product_no SET NOT NULL;
> ```

Why the word after `ADD` differ for constraints of different kinds?

Why does unique constraint has a more generic `ADD CONSTRAINT some_name` than check and foreign key?

Why is not null constraint specified by `ALTER COLUMN`, instead of `ADD CONSTRAINT some_name NOT NULL (col_name)`?

Is there inconsistency in PostgreSQL syntax of adding constraints to a table?
Does this belong to the SQL standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word after `ADD` differs so the database knows what you mean. E.g. `CHECK` introduces a generic boolean condition; `UNIQUE` is followed by a list of column names; `FOREIGN KEY` is followed by a column name, `REFERENCES`, and a target table/column. Without these keywords it would be ambiguous which kind of constraint you mean.

The `CONSTRAINT constraint_name` syntax is not limited to unique constraints. See the definition of *`column_constraint`* and *`table_constraint`* in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createtable.html; both allow an optional leading `CONSTRAINT constraint_name` to name the constraint.

As for `NOT NULL`, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-constraints.html#id-1.5.4.5.6:

> A not-null constraint is always written as a column constraint. **A not-null constraint is functionally equivalent to creating a check constraint `CHECK (column_name IS NOT NULL)`**, but in PostgreSQL creating an explicit not-null constraint is more efficient. The drawback is that you cannot give explicit names to not-null constraints created this way.

I assume not-null constraints are a special case internally, allowing for better optimization than a generic `CHECK` constraint, which can use any boolean expression.

Answer (score 1):

We cant use add constraint syntax for Not Null. You have to use modify column syntax to add not null
eg.
alter table  modify (  not null);

Comment: Thanks. Could you give an example of using `alter table modify ( not null)`?

Comment: alter table <tablename> modify (<columnname> <datatype> not null) ; eg. alter table products  modify (product_no bigint not null)